# Updated symfony in composer.json, but I get an error when trying to install a new package with "require"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, symfony5

I upgrade Symfony to the 5.0 version.

When I run the server, all is right. However, when I use composer (example composer remove tattali/calendar-bundle), I get these errors :

```
    C:\cmder\roadtrip>composer remove tattali/calendar-bundle
    Dependency "symfony/framework-bundle" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - The requested package symfony/console (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 2
        - The requested package symfony/dotenv (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/dotenv[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 3
        - The requested package symfony/filesystem (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 4
        - The requested package symfony/form (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/form[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 5
        - The requested package symfony/framework-bundle (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 6
        - The requested package symfony/intl (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/intl[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 7
        - The requested package symfony/property-access (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/property-access[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 8
        - The requested package symfony/security-bundle (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 9
        - The requested package symfony/serializer (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/serializer[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 10
        - The requested package symfony/translation (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 11
        - The requested package symfony/validator (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/validator[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 12
        - The requested package symfony/var-dumper (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 13
        - The requested package symfony/yaml (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
      Problem 14
        - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - Installation request for ocramius/package-versions (locked at 1.5.1) -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.5.1].


Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don't understand what I must do to solve this problem.

EDIT :

I updated Php to the last version, I resolved all depreciations, I changed the doctrine-extensions bundle to a bundle supported by Symfony 5. Now, I get theses errors :

```
C:\cmder\roadtrip>composer update knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/console (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package symfony/dotenv (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/dotenv[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package symfony/filesystem (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package symfony/form (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/form[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package symfony/framework-bundle (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package symfony/intl (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/intl[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 7
    - The requested package symfony/property-access (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/property-access[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 8
    - The requested package symfony/security-bundle (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 9
    - The requested package symfony/serializer (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/serializer[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 10
    - The requested package symfony/translation (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 11
    - The requested package symfony/validator (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/validator[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 12
    - The requested package symfony/var-dumper (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 13
    - The requested package symfony/yaml (locked at v4.4.4, required as 5.0.*) is satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 14
    - symfony/web-server-bundle v4.2.12 requires symfony/console ~3.4|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - symfony/web-server-bundle v4.2.12 requires symfony/console ~3.4|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - symfony/web-server-bundle v4.2.12 requires symfony/console ~3.4|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for symfony/web-server-bundle (locked at v4.2.12, required as 4.2.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/web-server-bundle[v4.2.12].
```

Comment: No, I don't have a a solution. I updated Php to the last version, I resolved all depreciations, I changed the doctrine-extensions bundle to a bundle supported by Symfony 5 but I always have this kind of error messages.

Comment: When I execute "composer update", I get the same errors.

Comment: Create a new Symfony 5 project then run "composer require tattali/calendar-bundle" and see what happens.  If you get errors then you know the bundle has not been updated for S5.  You can check on github to see if an update is at least scheduled.  If no errors then at least you know the problem is elsewhere.  Symfony and Composer work well for minor updates but major updates can be problematic.

Comment: It being a lazy Sunday morning I went ahead and followed by own suggestion.  No errors.  Now you should continue to install any other third party bundles your app uses.  If they all install cleanly then you can replace your existing composer.json with the new composer.json.

Comment: Can you share your composer.json please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem by removing the webserver bundle.